# How to migrate Java project from Eclipse to VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jsf, wildfly

I'm trying to migrate a Java project from Eclipse to VS Code, the project consist of a front and a backend, and both are supposed to run on a Wildfly Server at localhost. I want to have hot code reload when a .xhtml or .java file is modified, without having to manually compile a .war file and publish it to the server.
I'm using the Red Hat Server Connector plugin, but on the Wildfly server there is only and option for deploying a war file or a folder.

Is there a way to configure Maven to compile directly to wildfly\standalone\deployments? or some tutorial about how can I configure VS Code for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `Tomcat for Java` extension?

You can have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9mugpHWr14), at the `8:13` you can see the `Hot Code Replace` button.